# Spring data jdbc spel

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data

I tried to play with spring data jdbc after several month of spring data mongodb and jpa... And my surprise... I don't find my favorite function easily : Example, Predicate, Spel...

So, at this time, I tried to have a @query working with spel... and I have a doubt... it exists ????

```
2020-06-25 18:45:47.566 ERROR [,,,] 15472 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: No value supplied for the SQL parameter '#{#query.lastname}': No value registered for key '#{#query.lastname}'] with root cause

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: No value supplied for the SQL parameter '#{#query.lastname}': No value registered for key '#{#query.lastname}'
```

My request is very simple :

```
 public interface UserRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, Long> {

    User findByLastname(String lastname);

    @Query("select * from USER where lastname= :#{#query.lastname} and firstname= :#{#query.firstname} and age=:#{#query.age}")
    Page<User> findBySearchUserQuery(@Param("query") SearchUserQuery query, Pageable page);

}
```

Thx for your help, regards
Nico

Comment: This feature is now available with the 3.0.0 release of Spring Data JDBC. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

SpEL support became available with Spring Data JDBC 3.0 RC1 so if you update to a current version is should just work.

### Original answer

As of now Spring (until Spring Data JDBC 2.1) @Query supports only named parameters, no support using SPEL in @Query.
The simplest solution will be providing all parameters to query methods.

```
@Query("select u from USER as u where u.lastname= :lastname and u.firstname= :firstname and u.age=:age")
Page<User> findBySearchUserQueryParams(String firstname, String lastname, int age, Pageable page);
```

[Spring data jdbc reference document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/current/reference/html/#jdbc.query-methods)

Answer (score 0):

You should not write [*] in the query
but name the class as some name and return it

your query will be something like this

```
 @Query("select u from USER as u where u.lastname= :#{#query.lastname} and u.firstname= :#{#query.firstname} and u.age=:#{#query.age}")
    Page<User> findBySearchUserQuery(@Param("query") SearchUserQuery query, Pageable page);
```

Comment: Ok, I modified as recommanded, but same error... I missed something ?